# jquery dialog submit button cannot control enable/disable

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

I've been battling with this issue all day.  I am hoping someone has an answer for me.  I did a bunch of searching and can't seem to find an answer.

I have a page that has 3 forms on it. I am working within the 2nd form.  None of the forms are embedded within another form.

I have a hidden div that contains two form elements, a drop down list and a text box, and a submit button that I anticipated it posting to the form it is enclosed in.  On another button within the form itself (not submit button), I have javascript that launches jquery.Dialog, that code looks like this:

```
function showReleaseDiv() {
    var div = $("#ReleaseHoldsDiv");
    var f = div.closest("form");
    div.dialog({ width: 270, height: 187, modal: true, title: 'Bulk Hold Resolution' });
    div.parent().appendTo(f);
}
```

This part does function correctly. I've overcome the typical jquery issue where it pulls the contents of the dialog out of the form, so I put it back in the form, but wonder if this is causing my real issues which are:

The drop down list and text box are both required before I post, so I default the submit button to disabled, then I have an onchange event on the drop downlist, and the onkeyup on the text box call the following javascript:

```
function enablePopupRelease() {
    var button = $("PopupReleaseButton");
    if (button && button != null) {
        button.attr("disabled", "disabled");
        if ($("#ResolutionTypeCode").val() != "" && $("#ResolutionComments").val() != "") {
            button.removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Both events fire correctly and I step through the code; all seems fine, but the button disable state does not change.

Please help.

Comment: Side note, the `if(button && button != null)` is unnecessary, if nothing matches button, it will just be an empty jquery object. But if you do want to test, you should use `if(button.length)`

Comment: Using any method you wish, can you check to see if the attribute is actually removed?

Comment: Is there a '#' missing in the `var button = $("PopupReleaseButton");` line?

Comment: Yes, I just noticed that as well...

Comment: Holy #$@# !!!!  I reviewed this code so many times - I even had a coworker look at it!  Can you put bad words in here?  Damn it!  Good catch pluckerpluck!  I'm officially demoting my ability to post on stackoverflow!

Comment: doh - i gave credit to pluckerpluck - great catch Julian D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are missing a hash on this line:

Change:

```
var button = $("PopupReleaseButton");
```

to

```
var button = $("#PopupReleaseButton");
```

Answer (score 0):

firstly I would clean some code as follows:

```
function enablePopupRelease() {     var button = $("PopupReleaseButton");     if (button) {         button.attr("disabled", "disabled");         if ($("#ResolutionTypeCode").val() && $("#ResolutionComments").val()) {             button.removeAttr("disabled");         }     }     return true; }
```

Let me know if makes any difference please?

if you break through the code ... does it stop at button.removeAttr("disabled");    please?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the jQuery UI button widget for the form's submit button? If so, you will need to call

```
$("#PopupReleaseButton").button({disabled: true});
```

to disable the button.

Answer (score 0):

`disabled` isn't an attribute, it's a property -- try using `button.prop('disabled',true)` and `button.prop('disabled',false)` instead.

http://api.jquery.com/prop/